# How group again a grouped query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a query in order to get student count by cities.

A table (`Address`) holds records of students' address information.

```
AddressID, StudentID, Address, City, Country, Telephone
```

are some fields of Address table. There is one point which I must tell about: City column values consists of 7 chars.

Each city has a unique offset number starting with 1, and first 9 cities loose the 0's at the beginning.

**CASE I**: If the student resides in city 09 and if it is center its city column has `900000`. As you can see, city codes less than 10 have 6 character length.

**CASE II**: If the student resides in a city but in a town of it, city code changes according to town's code like `900001`.

Now I am querying student count for each city with the query below but I have got repetitive rows for some cities. It brings student count living in the city center, and in a town of it seperately so I have got some result like that:

```
stuCnt cityCode
------ --------
   102       01
   240       02
    21       03
    54       03

SELECT COUNT(StudentID) AS stuCnt, 
       RIGHT('00' + ISNULL(LEFT(City, LEN(City) - 5), ''), 2) AS cityCode 
FROM Address 
GROUP BY City
ORDER BY City
```

How can I get a result like the following?

```
stuCnt cityCode
------ --------
   102       01
   240       02
    75       03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just group by the calculated value:

```
select
    count(StudentID) as stuCnt, 
    right('00' + isnull(left(City, len(City) - 5), ''), 2) as cityCode 
from
    address 
group by
    right('00' + isnull(left(City, len(City) - 5), ''), 2)
order by
    right('00' + isnull(left(City, len(City) - 5), ''), 2)
```

in some versions of SQL, you can use cityCode in the order by, rather than rewriting the calculation:

```
select
    count(StudentID) as stuCnt, 
    right('00' + isnull(left(City, len(City) - 5), ''), 2) as cityCode 
from
    address 
group by
    right('00' + isnull(left(City, len(City) - 5), ''), 2)
order by
    cityCode
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the first query in an Inner `SELECT`, and group those results with a `SUM`:

```
SELECT  SUM(stuCnt) As stuCnt,
        cityCode
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(StudentID) AS stuCnt, 
           RIGHT('00' + ISNULL(LEFT(City, LEN(City) - 5), ''), 2) AS cityCode 
    FROM Address 
    GROUP BY City
) X
GROUP BY cityCode
ORDER BY cityCode
```

Answer (score 2):

I like Cross Apply: faster than nested queries and faster than parsing the city 3 times per record.

```
SELECT COUNT(StudentID) AS stuCnt, tmp1.cityCode 
FROM Address 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT RIGHT('00' + ISNULL(LEFT(City, LEN(City) - 5), ''), 2) cityCode) as Tmp1
GROUP BY cityCode 
ORDER BY cityCode
```

Comment: I like this query most but server says that CROSS APPLY is not supported.

Comment: Couldn't get this query to work as written. Tried putting the second `from address` inside the definition of tmp1, but it gets the wrong answer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c50b2/6

Comment: Really? What are you using, SQL 2000 or before?

Comment: I like not having to type the formula three times, but there's no difference in query plan between the two. Seems the SQL Optimizer is bright enough to eliminate the redundant calculations.